# Cannot create Git remote on FreeBsd version 6.0 using git version 1.4

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to get some code in an old server running freebsd version 6 with git version 1.4.1 on to github.  I'm trying to add a remote to the repo referencing GitHub.com repo.

Does anyone have or know how to get the old command reference for version 1.4 of Git.

I tried editing the .git/config file and adding both a http ref or an ssh ref but both come back with errors.

[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@github.com:xxx-yyyy/aYYYv.com.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

ssh ref says: ssh: github.com:xxx-yyyy: hostname nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: unexpected EOF

when using https link

[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/xxx-yyyy/aYYYv.com.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Error: no DAV locking support on remote repo https://github.com/xxx-yyyy/aYYYv.com.git